# If Planet 9 is indeed a black hole, what kinds of things could we learn from it?

Tags: physics, black-hole

[I saw a recent paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1909.11090) speculating that planet 9 might actually be a primordial black hole. I've heard people say that if true, this would be a new era for science. But specifically, what could we learn from having a black hole so close to our solar system? What kind of experiments could we conduct?

Comment: First of all, this would suggest that primordial black holes are awfully abundant

Comment: The Supplementary material section of that paper includes an exact scale (1:1) illustration of a 5 Earth mass PBH which has a Schwarzschild radius of 4.5cm :) !

Comment: @SolomonSlow I've retracted my vote but I think still Astronomy.SE would be a better site for 'what can we learn?' and only with these answers we can begin speculating here 'how can we learn that?'

Comment: This was a theory oresented by an MIT research group which had enough buzzwords to be published by major news outlets. As far as I know it has not been substantiated by evidence.

Comment: @gandalf61 oh, how cool! It's an "Exact scale (1:1) illustration"

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen and if abundant, could they account for the "missing" dark matter?

Comment: @Anthony probably not within what we consider the Galaxy.  There is so much dark matter that if it were among the stars we'd see it affecting the orbits of (exo)planets.  Most dark matter has to be above and below the observed galactic disks or in intergalactic space.

Comment: This is blowing my mind, is there a good forum/site that kinda breaks this sort of news/papers?

Comment: @AnthonyX: no.  If dark matter was massive compact objects, then we would detect it because of gravitational micro-lensing.  We don't.